# SELinux forbits ACPI/udev hook to use sudo

Tags: selinux

I have a ThinkPad X220 Tablet which has a twistable display. The thinkpad-scripts collection which I wrote with a friend hooks into the hardware event (as root) and then runs a script. This is the udev file:

```
event=ibm/hotkey HKEY 00000080 0000500[9a]
action=/usr/bin/thinkpad-rotate-hook %e
```

The called script ([full source](https://github.com/martin-ueding/thinkpad-scripts/blob/master/tps/hooks.py#L123)) then calls the user script as the currently logged in user via `sudo` like so:

```
sudo -u $user -i env DISPLAY=:0.0 /usr/bin/thinkpad-rotate $set_to --via-hook
```

This has been working fine on Ubuntu and Arch Linux. On Fedora however, this has never worked. Looking into the system log, I found the following:

```
audit[28666]: AVC avc:  denied  { setgid } for  pid=28666 comm="sudo" capability=6  scontext=system_u:system_r:apmd_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:system_r:apmd_t:s0 tclass=capability permissive=0
```

I also filed a [bug report](https://github.com/martin-ueding/thinkpad-scripts/issues/116) against my own project to keep track of what I have learned so far.

As far as I understand SELinux, I now need to add a rule to SELinux that allows this to happen. Where do I have to start reading to figure out what to do?

Comment: As a start, maybe you can create a rule using audit2allow based on the existing logs? See https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Security-Enhanced_Linux/sect-Security-Enhanced_Linux-Fixing_Problems-Allowing_Access_audit2allow.html for details.